# How to separate text and image path using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following strings:

```
this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details
```

```
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you
```

```
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me
```

How can I separate the text and image path using `RegExp`?

This is the expected result:

```
this was the url
```

```
SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END
```

```
click here to view details
```

Comment: You're supposed to try yourself, before asking. Please show your attemp and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also separate the image path and the text using this regular expression:

```
/(.*?)(SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH.+?SERVER_UPLOAD_END)(.+)/
```

This will always return you three groups where the first can be empty.

Here is an example of how you can use the regular expression:

```js
const a = ['this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details',
    'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you',
    'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me'];

const regex = /(.*?)(SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH.+?SERVER_UPLOAD_END)(.+)/;

a.forEach(s => {
    const match = s.match(regex);
    match.forEach((m, i) => console.log(i, m.trim()));
    console.log()
});
```

The group at index 0 is always the original string. The interesting groups start from index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `RegExp` to match the text you don't want:

## `[^ ]{20,}`

It matches the unwanted strings because they are the only character sequences that continue on for at least `20` characters without a single space.

`[^ ]` means no space. `{20,}` means repeated at least `20` times.

Then `.split()` the entire string using the unwanted text as a delimiter.

```js
[
  'this was the url SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::5e2650c2-728c-40af-99a4eb100c432091.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END click here to view details',
  'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::68d37b07-d694-47af-a16a-8adbe400ac67.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Hector where are you Hello world how are you',
  'SERVER_UPLOAD_FILE_PATH____::ad4d7360-9c6c-44fa-bcbb-0db7e671e036.png____SERVER_UPLOAD_END Execuse Me'
].map(s => s.split(s.match(/[^ ]{20,}/)))
  .flat()
  .map(s => s.trim())
  .filter(Boolean)
  .forEach(s => console.log(s));
```